# Python 2.7, Requests Version 2.2.1

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

Using Python 2.7, anyone know why I get this with requests 2.2.1 but not ver 1.2.3?And how to fix this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "krunchuploader.py", line 12, in <module>
    from modules.core import confirm_customer_ddi, get_apikey
  File "/home/one/trunk/stratus-krunch-uploader/stratus_krunch_uploader/modules/core.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import chardet
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .request import RequestMethods
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/request.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .filepost import encode_multipart_formdata
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/filepost.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .fields import RequestField
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/bot/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/fields.py", line 7, in <module>
    import email.utils
ImportError: No module named utils
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a file email.py that I renamed, but the email.pyc was still causing the issue.